# What is eating the base of bell pepper plant?

Tags: vegetables, bell-peppers

I live in San Francisco Bay area. Till last year I did not have this problem. Something is eating the base of my bell pepper plant which is about 18 inches tall and producing. The critter is eating just the base of the plant and the plant is falling off and dying. It is like someone just cut it at the base. It is not touching the leaves are the bell peppers. I thought it is gopher and I put bites in all the holes around the backyard. I have also added chili powder to the base. This morning I saw that the base of another plant is chewed (only a little) and hopefully this plant will survive. I noticed that it tried to chew from the side the chili powder is not present. Mostly they were eaten when it was dark though once it happened in the afternoon too. I have eggplant, okra, tomato and other vegetable plants. But none of them were touched. I had very small Thai pepper plants but were eaten by critters.  Please help me finding out who the critter is and how to get rid of it.  Thanks
[image: survived bell pepper plant]

[image: dead bell pepper plant]